# Find the limit of $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin[xf(x)]}{x\cdot\sin[f(x)]}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

Let $f(x)$ is a continuous function which satisfies that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$. Then whether

> $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin[xf(x)]}{x\cdot\sin[f(x)]}=1$$

If not, then can we impose some constraints on $f(x)$ to approach the limit?

Comment: I think you should add the hypothesis that $\lim_{x\to \infty}x\cdot f(x)=0$. Use the Limit Theorem for Composite Functions: $\lim_{u\to \infty}h(u)=M$ and $\lim_{x\to a}u(x)=L$ implies $\lim_{x\to a}h(u(x))=M$

Comment: If $f(x)=1/x$, then $\frac{\sin (x f(x))}{x \sin f(x)} = \sin 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing up the discussion in comments:

1. Since $f\to 0$, it follows that $\sin (f(x))/f(x)\to 1$. Therefore, the behavior  of the given limit is the same as of 
   $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin[xf(x)]}{x\,f(x)}$$
2. To simplify notation, write $g(x)=x\,f(x)$.
3. When can we say that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin[g(x)]}{g(x)}=1\quad ?$$
   Only if we know that $g(x)\to 0$. The function $(\sin t)/t$ is strictly less than $1$ in absolute value for all $t\ne 0$. If $g$ fails to converge to $0$, the above limit fails to be equal to $1$ (or to exist).